# Appending data in specific table by id - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

i have a function here to add more rows on table but the problem is this function will apply in all table on page.
how can i add more function for specific ID table ???

```
$(".add").on('click',function(){
        count=$('table tr').length;
        var data='<tr><td>some text or html</td></tr';
        $('table').append(data);
});
```

please help, i just script kiddie in web program ^_^

Comment: _script kiddie_ we need to see the markup too. because of your add button where it resides in your markup.

Comment: add a specific ID to the table,answer is in the guestion :))

Comment: instead of `$('table').` use `$('#your_id').`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give one id to the table and update function like this:

```
$(".add").on('click',function(){
        count=$('#table1 tr').length;
        var data='<tr><td>some text or html</td></tr';
        $('#table1').append(data);
});
```

Where table1 is the id of the table to which you want to append row.